# libvorbisfile: vorbis_info->channels не проинициализировано

Tags: c, аудио, decode, ogg

```
FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb");
vorbis_info* info;
OggVorbis_File oggFile;

ov_open(file, &oggFile, NULL, 0);
info = ov_info(&oggFile, -1);
```

Значение `info->channels` при каждом запуске разное, с огромным разбросом. Ogg файл сохранен через Audacity как `ogg vorbis` со стандартными настройками (там только степень сжатия). И со стерео, и с моно, результат такой-же.

Другие поля, как `rate` верны.

Версия vorbis: `Xiph.Org libVorbis 1.3.5`

`OV_EVERSION = -134`

Часто `channel = 0` или ~32k(c разбросом)

Comment: Что возвращает функция ov_open?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, ov_open возвращает 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Баг мог наблюдаться в других программах, использующих эту библиотеку.
Как это часто бывает, у `libvorbis` в системе была очень старая версия, и в ней был этот баг. После установки новой версии библиотеки всё стало работать правильно.